# Alfresco installation on ubuntu 12.04 with existing efront deployment

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, alfresco

I am having following setup on my machine.

Ubuntu 12.04(LTS) 32-bit

Apache2

MySql

PHP

I have created this setup to run efront community edition, i am also running a helpdesk software on the same server the example URLs are as follows.

```
    http://myip/efront
    http://myip/helpdesk
```

Now I want to install alfresco and host it as follows

```
    http://myip/alfresco
```

Data of efront and helpdesk is hosted on /var/www directory
I have not created any virtual hosts, i am just using sub-directories under www and using above mentioned url to access different applications.

Can anyone help me out for this deployment? I have seen lot of blogs but every one of them refers to standard tomcat installation.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this so here is my setup.

Open Apache2 “httpd.conf”.

Make copy of “httpd.conf” so we can always have a backup and then edit “httpd.conf”.

Uncomment or add these lines after LoadModule section:

```
#Mode JK
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
#Mode SSL
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

Also add these lines (replace 'path-to' accordingly):

```
<IfModule jk_module>
          JkWorkersFile "/path-to/workers.properties"


          # Where to put jk logs
          JkLogFile "/path-to/logs/mod_jk.log"


          # Set the jk log level [debug/error/info]
          JkLogLevel info


          # Select the log format
          JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "


          # JkOptions indicate to send SSL KEY SIZE,
          JkOptions +ForwardKeySize -ForwardDirectories


          # JkRequestLogFormat set the request format
          JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"


          # Alfresco mount points (last parameter is name of worker defined in workers.properties)
          JkMount /alfresco/service alfresco
          JkMount /alfresco/service/* alfresco
</IfModule>
```

Now we have to create a “workers.properties” file if it doesnot exist and copy the path to above code.

Here is the 'workers.properties' content:

```
worker.list=alfresco,tango
worker.alfresco.port=8011
worker.alfresco.host=IP_ADDRESS
worker.alfresco.type=ajp13
worker.alfresco.lbfactor=1
```

Now go to “\tomcat\conf” and open “server.xml”.
Find this string “protocol="AJP/1.3"” in the file and edit the line like this:

```
<Connector port="8011" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

(Note: here “8011” is the port we defined in “workers.properties” file for alfresco)

Save all these files and restart apache2 then Alfresco. you are done.

Comment: So I have to follow standard installation of alfresco on tomcat and then carry out this process. Is that correct. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: yup install as usual and use these configuration. you'll be good.